# Adding constraints programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

What is the translation to java code of the following XML instructions used in a layout definition with a constraint layout?

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/Button1"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Button1"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/Button2"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="Button2"
```

Comment: Check this out http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Managing_Constraints_using_ConstraintSet

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is an example of adding constraints programatically,

```
ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout  = (ConstraintLayout)fndViewById(R.id.mainConstraint);
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
mConstraintLayout.addView(view,0);
set.clone(mConstraintLayout);
set.connect(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, mConstraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 60);
set.applyTo(mConstraintLayout);
```

To know more details you can refer [Constraint layout](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Managing_Constraints_using_ConstraintSet)

Comment: When i add view according to above answer and remove button and reset constraints as according to xml i`m having the exception "All children of ConstraintLayout must have ids to use ConstraintSet"

Comment: @AsadMukhtar you might need to add an ID to your view then. In the example above, the ImageView ID can be set with `view.id = View.generateViewId()`.

Comment: Thanks but i fixed it by declaring id as attribute in attrs file

Answer (score 0):

Adding constraints to a programmatically generated view is also possible without creating a new constraint set, but simply by just setting the layout parameters of the view. Here is an example in Kotlin and Java:

```kotlin
val tv = TextView(requireContext())
tv.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
).apply {
    topToTop = R.id.Button1
    bottomToBottom = R.id.Button1
    leftToLeft = R.id.Button2
    rightToRight = R.id.Button2
}

val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.myLayout)
layout.addView(tv)
```

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
layoutParams.topToTop = R.id.Button1;
layoutParams.bottomToBottom = R.id.Button1;
layoutParams.leftToLeft = R.id.Button2;
layoutParams.rightToRight = R.id.Button2;

TextView tv = new TextView(requireContext());
tv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
layout.addView(tv);
```

It is also easy to modify the layout parameters after a view has already been added to a layout. Again an example in Kotlin and Java:

```kotlin
tv.layoutParams = (tv.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams).apply {
    topToTop = R.id.Button3
    bottomToBottom = R.id.Button3
}
```

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) tv.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.topToTop = R.id.Button3;
layoutParams.bottomToBottom = R.id.Button3;
tv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Just don't forget to re-assign the modified layout parameters to the view. Otherwise the changes won't be applied.