# How to set EditText layout margin programmatically?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, margins

How to set EditText layout margin programmatically in Android? I wanna set the margins for the new editText that comes when you press the floatingactionbutton. It's about input of various activities which I want to be placed down a line with each one being placed underneath the one before it. Remember that this is constraint layout.

I have read a lot of posts on how to do so but nothing seems to work for me.

Here is my code:

```java
public class planlaeg extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    Button button4;
    private ConstraintLayout mLayout;
    private EditText mEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_planlaeg);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openNewActivity();
            }
        });
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(nyrejse.getValue());

        mEditText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        mLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.planlaeg_l);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                mLayout.addView(createNewEditText(mEditText.getText().toString()));
            }
        });
    }

    public void openNewActivity(){
        Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent5);
    }

    private EditText createNewEditText(String text) {
        final EditText et = new EditText(this);
        et.setText(text);
        return et;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728484/8906488) answer for setting margin in general view. But if the `EditText` is inside `ConstraintLayout` you have to have constraint on the EditText for the side which you want to add margin. For example, if you want to add margin to the **end** of the view, you have to set **layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf** or **layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf** in the EditText. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46401250/8906488) answer for adding constraint programatically.

Comment: I could not get it to work. The new editTexts the floating action button create still jumps to 0,0.

Comment: dont know. How to i do it?